# Error in gallery slider..

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have made a simple gallery using jquery but the left right buttons are not working ??

I have used jquery function `first().appendTo`  and `last().prependTo`

Plz check the link below

[Mydemo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/FDrh9/2/)

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: That demo doesn't work and it's unclear(?)

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX i know its not working ..can u plz make it work..

Comment: that is not at all correct code.there is no script that will make next and previous button work.

Comment: @user1145009 Sorry, but seems that you didn't tried it if that demo is your current work. Also, you can search through internet many of image sliders made in jQuery and free. Just implement them, it's my suggestion.

Comment: Now check you demo, your right button is working now. By the same way you can make left button working. Proceed towards proper code then ask if feel stuck somewhere.

Link is here: http://jsfiddle.net/FDrh9/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery file + bootstrap plugin

Here the demo

> `jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/566/`

For more information visit [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel)